# How do you parse a diff file created with pysvn?

Tags: python, svn, diff, pysvn

Does pysvn have a way to parse diff files it creates?  I want to extra the filename/filepath, head revision of each contained file, total lines changed, total files changed, etc.

If not, is there a manual way to do it?  I need to parse a diff file that starts with "Index:" for each file contained in the diff but I don't know the exact format of these files.  So if pysvn doesn't have a way of parsing this I need to figure out what the format is and do it myself (in Python).  Is format an SVN-specific format?  Is it published?  Python sample code for parsing it would be great!

Comment: I'm trying to help answer my own question.  Is this format called the "unified diff format" by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to write a few lines of custom code using [this](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~bzr-pqm/bzr/bzr.dev/view/head:/bzrlib/patches.py).  It totally saved the day, so big-ups to Aaron Bentley!

Comment: You may get more upvotes if you explain how you used the linked code to solve your problem.